# Cannot get the passing values from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

If I run jsp, while exporting the contents to excel, I am not getting the values in downloaded excel file. It is simply empty. Here what I tried..

How to pass the table values to servlet?

Excel.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ page import ="javax.swing.JOptionPane"%>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Export to Excel - Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table align="left" border="2">
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor="lightgreen">
                <th>Sr. No.</th>
                <th>Text Data</th>
                <th>Number Data</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <%
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            %>
            <tr bgcolor="lightblue">
                <td align="center"><%=i + 1%></td>
                <td align="center">This is text data <%=i%></td>
                <td align="center"><%=i * i%></td>
            </tr>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <a href="Sample?exportToExcel=YES">Export to Excel</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Sample.java (Servlet)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class Sample extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Sample() {
        super();
    }


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    

        String exportToExcel = request.getParameter("exportToExcel");

        if (exportToExcel != null
                && exportToExcel.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="
                    + "excel.xls");    
        }  
    }    

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }  
}
```

Comment: You are not getting the values in to the Excel sheet because you are not passing the values to the servlet. And how are you getting the values to be displayed inside your JSP?

Comment: @user3619962 use forms ...for that use hidden field then retrieve it in the servlet

Comment: Can you please post the updated code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Couldn't get the values from jsp to servlet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424327/couldnt-get-the-values-from-jsp-to-servlet)

Comment: @Santino'Sonny'Corleone: Do you know there is an answer there? If you can, answer for this and post comment

Comment: @user3152748 might as well delete that post..no need to spam if u arent getting ny answer..

Comment: kk...gud..+1 for that..

Comment: What values do you want to pass, the content of the `<tr bgcolor="lightblue">` rows ? And do you *really* want to build a xls file or only a csv one ?

Comment: @user3152748 did u get ur answer?

Comment: @user3152748 delete the current post or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424327/couldnt-get-the-values-from-jsp-to-servlet) one. You shouls not spam out of desperation of getting the answer

Comment: why is the servlet needed write the export related code in scriptlet it will be simple

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to `Export` the table (*OR Web page*) to `excel` file you need to write your download (*response*) code inside the **SAME** `.jsp` so in your case.

Add following in your `Excel.jsp` file.

```
   <%//Use scriptlet
        if (exportToExcel != null
            && exportToExcel.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename="
                + "excel.xls");    
    }  
    %>
    //In short COPY whole code from Servlet's get method and paste it in Scriplet
```

So here you are apparently calling your own `.jsp` and handling the request and as `exportToExcel` is equal to `YES` it will give you the file with content on your `.jsp`.

Comment: I used this scriplet in jsp and it is working. I need to pass the parameter to servlet and process this request

Comment: You can set all data in hidden fields and pass it to servlet where you need to write to the file and than set response.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are downloading  a excel file with out any content .you have to read the values from table and write it in to an excel file . then add the file into the response stream.

the following code may help you.

```
   public class WriteExcelDemo 
 {
   public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    //Blank workbook
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 

    //Create a blank sheet
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Employee Data");

    //This data needs to be written (Object[])
    Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
    data.put("1", new Object[] {"ID", "NAME", "LASTNAME"});
    data.put("2", new Object[] {1, "Amit", "Shukla"});
    data.put("3", new Object[] {2, "Lokesh", "Gupta"});
    data.put("4", new Object[] {3, "John", "Adwards"});
    data.put("5", new Object[] {4, "Brian", "Schultz"});

    //Iterate over data and write to sheet
    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for (String key : keyset)
    {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        for (Object obj : objArr)
        {
           Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
           if(obj instanceof String)
                cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
            else if(obj instanceof Integer)
                cell.setCellValue((Integer)obj);
        }
    }
    try
    {
        //Write the workbook in file system
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new   File("howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: it would be better if u explain the code...rather then just copy paste .see how task has explained in his answer..